WSO2 Identity Server (wso2is-6.1.0) - Admin User Gets Logged Out Abruptly in a Clustered Setup
I have setup wso2is-6.1.0 in a clustered setup in Kubernetes. I have used the below configuration in the deployment.toml in order to configure clustering.
[clustering]
membership_scheme = "kubernetes"
local_member_host = "$env{NODE_IP}"
local_member_port = "4000"

[clustering.properties]
KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE = "<namespace>"
KUBERNETES_SERVICES = "<service>"

However, after exposing the pods as a load balancer service and logging in to the carbon console using admin user, the user gets logged out abruptly while performing actions in the carbon console. This does not occur if the number of pods are reduced to one.
A direction to resolve this issue is much appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

How do you expose the IS server outside the cluster? Is it via the Nginx Ingress or something else?

This looks like a session affinity issue. If you are deploying WSO2 IS with Nginx make sure you have the following annotations in the Nginx Ingress.
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/backend-protocol: "HTTPS"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/affinity: "cookie"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-name: "route"
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/session-cookie-hash: "sha1"

https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-is/blob/6.1.x/advanced/is-pattern-1/values.yaml#L121-L124
If you are having Ingress controller other than Nginx, make sure the session affinity is set properly.
Update:
If you are using the LoadBalancer service type in K8s service, then you can set the session affinity as ClientIP to make this work. https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity

hi @Pubci In my setup I am simply exposing the IS as a Load Balancer service in GCP. No Nginx is involved. Also, shouldn't the clustering configurations handle the session affinity? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

No, Clustering will not handle this. In this case you can apply session affinity at the K8s Service level - https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/networking/virtual-ips/#session-affinity
Only Client IP based is available.
